# Check for user Input on stdin during whole execution time

Tags: python, multithreading, user-input, stdin, cpu-usage

My current python script listens to the network and if there is a certain event, the event is saved into a list.

The thing is, the user is also displayed the event and should react to it, but it is not necessary to do it immediately, so he gets the message displayed, with some choices, but he could also react (press yes or no) at some later point. With his choice, he is also supplying information, that makes it possible to see which event he meant (like: yes event 123).

My question is: How is it possible to wait for his input the whole time of execution? My approach so far was `select.select()` in a while loop (`while(1)`) in a new thread, so the remaining execution process is not blocked:

```
while(1):
  if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
    result = parse_userinput()
    react_to_event(result)
```

But: The CPU is running very, very high, because of the endless loop in the thread that constantly checks for input.

Is there any better approach to check for user input on `stdin` during the whole execution time of the python script?

Comment: Adding a long timeout would help lots. Try `select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 10)[0]`.

Comment: I agree with @matsjoyce. If your loop is just waiting for input from `sys.stdin` and nothing else, just make the `select` timeout longer. It'll free up your CPU with no adverse effects on anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the waiting is done in a new thread, you should use the [timeout](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/select.html#select.select) option:

```
while True:
    if select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 10)[0]:
        ...
```

You can set the `timeout` option to be nearly any value, as you do not need to do anything else in this thread, and `select` returns as soon as `sys.stdin` is ready, so you can set `timeout` to be `5`, `10` or `10**9`. Note (you may already know this, but it may be useful for others) that the user does need to press return, and then the user's input can be gotten though `input` (or `raw_input` in Python 2).

On a side note, as you are only checking one file/socket, you can just use normal Pythonic empty list checking, and remove the `sys.stdin in` (as shown above).

Comment: I already knew it, but you get +1 and the correct answer, since you forced me to properly read the select documentation (actually the timeout part). Thanks man!